# XML remove Namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have this XML :

```
<mes:Fichier xmlns:mes="http://file.message.fr">
   <mes:toto>XXXXX</mes:toto>
   <yyy:Document xmlns:yyy="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.02y.001.01:Forward">
      <yyy:id>1<yyy:id>   
   </yyy:Document>
   <yyy:Document xmlns:yyy="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.02y.001.01:Forward">
      <yyy:id>2<yyy:id>   
   </yyy:Document>
</mes:Fichier>
```

I would like to split this one for each Document tag :
With my example :

File1 :

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.02y.001.01:Forward">
   <id>1<id>   
</Document>
```

File2 :

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:acmt.02y.001.01:Forward">
   <id>2<id>   
</Document>
```

I have implemented this xsl but i dont know how to remove all namespaces prefixe in the output files and set the href with a parameter.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(local-name(), 'Document')]">
            <xsl:result-document href="file{position()}.xml">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to remove all namespaces prefixe in the output files.
How can i do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to remove the namespaces or just the prefixes? Your input XML doesn't have namespace declarations for the prefixes. Please post the whole XSLT and the expected output. Also, mention the XSLT version you're using

Comment: @LingamurthyCS i have updated my question

Comment: What do you mean by "*set the href with a parameter*"?

Comment: @michael.hor257k for example : use a parameter when i call my XSLT :::::: transformer.setParameter("FILENAME", "MyFileName");  :::::::Use it to build the file name:::::::<xsl:result-document href="$FILENAME{position()}.xml">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont know how to remove all namespaces prefixe in the output files ...

Try:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[contains(local-name(), 'Document')]">
        <xsl:result-document href="file{position()}.xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

> ... and set the href with a parameter.

To use a parameter named `FILENAME` instead of the string "file", add this to the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:param name="FILENAME">
```

and change:

```
<xsl:result-document href="file{position()}.xml">
```

to:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$FILENAME}{position()}.xml">
```